# How can I prevent <divs> from overflowing a scrollbar down?

Tags: html

I have a div which allows me to have a scrollbar scroll horizontally, however when I place another div inside it, it simply starts to scroll vertically. How can I prevent this? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: please include your code so we have a real example instead of making assumptions

Comment: `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: @code the OP said vertically. Maybe that vertical overflow is caused by the horizontal showing up?

Comment: @diego then make it a `y`. There's no telling what the OP is really going for here.

Comment: but as you can see we are in the realm of speculations because there are no clear details yet.. until then I don't think there's a chance to address this question. Yes you can hide the overflows in general.. but I don't think that's the real issue. Very often the question as stated doesn't hold the real problem and that's true as more details are lacking

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should present some code samples in your question I assume that your problem can be solved by adding

```css
overflow-y: "hidden"
```

to the CSS of your wrapper div.

So something like

```html
<div style="overflow-y: hidden">
  <div>something</div>
</div>
```

should do the job.